# SQL Performance update with double nested subquery

Tags: sql, postgresql, query-optimization

I'm trying to update a Person table with a value from a Person Detail table.

I need to update a column value in person 1 with an A value from Person 1 Detail where B is the max value from the group of rows related to person 1 until person 3 million.

A query that resolved the problem is:

```
update person 
set A = subquery.A
from (
    select id , A
    from person_detail  pd 
    where B = ( select max( B ) from  person_detail pd2 where  pd2.id = pd.id ) as subquery
where s.id = person.id;
```

An important issue about the above solution is the extremely poor performance execution time of this solution. Any idea or recommendation on how to improve performance?

[image]

Edit: PostgreSQL Explain

```
"Update on person (cost=83690027.90..99774746.68 rows=1949368 width=465)"
"  ->  Merge Join  (cost=83690027.90..99774746.68 rows=1949368 width=465)"
"        Merge Cond: (subquery.id= person.id)"
"        ->  Subquery Scan on a  (cost=83688759.49..96359650.45 rows=1949368 width=58)"
"              Filter: (a.ranked_order = 1)"
"              ->  WindowAgg  (cost=83688759.49..91486230.85 rows=389873568 width=29)"
"                    ->  Sort  (cost=83688759.49..84663443.41 rows=389873568 width=21)"
"                          Sort Key: pd.id, pd.B DESC" 
"                          ->  Seq Scan on person_detail ad  (cost=0.00..23488027.68 rows=389873568 width=21)"
"        ->  Index Scan using person_id_A_B_C_D on person  (cost=0.43..3378840.19 rows=3313406 width=394)"
```

Table Structure

```
Table Person
    id PK
    A  

Table Person_detail
    id  PK
    A   PK
    B   PK
    C
```

Comment: please post the explain plan and your schema

Comment: Your schema is wrong. According to your update, person should have an A column?

Comment: Yes, you're right I did the edition

Answer (score 0):

Try using `distinct on ()` to find the row with the highest b

```
update person 
    set a = s.a
from (
  select distinct on (id) id, a
  from person_detail
  order by id, b desc
) as s
where s.id = person.id
```

An index on `person_detail (id, b desc, a)` should help